# .text issue in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on creating a simple calculator. I'm stuck on the display issue. I have all the buttons in the button class. When I try to display anything using for example $(".display").text(output); it doesn't work. I have a display class to be selected, it's under a tag that can have text, and output is a variable that is equal to something. I tried comparing with some other code I had that involved changing text with variables but I don't see what the issue is.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles.css">
         <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="calculator-background row">
            <p class="calc-title">Free Code Camp Calculator</p>
            <div class="row answer-box"><p class="display"></p></div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button">AC</button>
                <button type="button">CE</button>
                <button type="button">%</button>
                <button type="button">/</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button">7</button>
                <button type="button">8</button>
                <button type="button">9</button>
                <button type="button">*</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button">4</button>
                <button type="button">5</button>
                <button type="button">6</button>
                <button type="button">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button">1</button>
                <button type="button">2</button>
                <button type="button">3</button>
                <button type="button">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="button">.</button>
                <button type="button">0</button>
                <button type="button">Ans</button>
                <button type="button">=</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="resources/calculator.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var output = "";

    /* Calculator buttons */

    // only buttons are calculator buttons
    $("button").click(function(){
        // gets the text label of the button?
        var input = $(this).text();
        // if, else if chain for calculator functions
        if(input !== "AC" && input !== "CE" && input !== "Ans" && input !== "=")
            {
                output += input;
            }
        else if(input === "=")
            {
                output = eval(output);
            }
        else if(input === "CE" && output.length > 0)
            {
                output = output.slice(0,-1);
            }
        else if(input === "AC" && output.length > 0)
            {
                output = "";
            }
        else if(input === "Ans")
            {
                output = output;
            }
        // test to see if output wasn't getting anything
        output = 5;
        // display result in display class, doesn't display anything
        $(".display").text(output);
    });  

});
```

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle, hit Ans, and received a 5 - it seems to be working appropriately. https://jsfiddle.net/gg0tce8v/

Comment: it does work in the fiddle... I'm so confused why this isn't working for me... it also works splendidly when I take out the output = 5 line. The plot thickens on why this isn't working. I'm using brackets and the live preview, do you think that could be it? dumb question never mind i'll keep looking

Comment: Please share the link of fiddle where you're trying. It worked for me as well.

Comment: Wait - is this a direct cut/copy?  Do you have the javascript OUTSIDE of your closing HTML tag?

Comment: Nevermind - I see you reference it in a separate file.

Comment: I think he has that he has included the script in calculator.js file. I tried including the given script in the html page inside script tag. It worked here as well. I think you're giving incorrect path.

Comment: I made a fiddle where it doesn't work! maybe you'll be able to see the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/2fyftj7a/

Comment: It actually IS setting it, but the text is in the same color as the background so you can't see it. inspect element and you'll see the value is set

Comment: LOL... change the color property of .display.  LOL

Comment: Excellent so I'm an idiot. Well live and learn. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the color of your text is white

add this to your css

```
.display {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Here is the updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/2fyftj7a/1/

Answer (score 0):

The font color inherited by `<p class='display'></p>` is white, so you can't see it.

Add this your `.display` class...

```
color: #000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you still have an issue where you check for:

```
output.length
```

you might have to change that to:

```
output.toString().length
```